# php_value auto_prepend - causing 500 error?

Tags: php, apache

I have a project which uses the following in .htaccess:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /home/-path-here/prepend.php
```

This works fine on my local WAMP server and on another server, just not on this new one.

I have full access to the server.

I'm thinking I need to enable `php_value` something like php.ini or with easyapache?

Comment: does the new server have an existing value set for auto_prepend_file (check phpinfo();)

Comment: Check your Apache configuration. Specifically the value of `AllowOverride` for your (virtual)host.

Comment: The apache error log will have exact details on what's causing the 500 error. most likely as oswald says below - you don't have AllowOverride enabled, so php_value is disabled/invalid.

Comment: AllowOverride pilots .htaccess reading, if the php_value is on the apache conf and not .htaccess it won't cause any problem.

Comment: @nikc with AllowOverride disabled ANY .htaccess content would not affect anything. Go figure

Comment: Here goes a real answer unlike these lame ones. 1. **Every time you see 500 error, you obliged to check server's error_log to see actual error message.** It will let you know what caused an error. 2. php_value works with PHP as apache module only. See SErver API section in phpinfo()

Answer (score 5):

To allow `php_value` in `.htaccess` files, the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive for that directory must be configured appropriately.

```
AllowOverride All
```

would do it, but that might be to general. Then again, I do not know whether a stricter setting exists that still lets you put PHP configuration options in `.htaccess`.

For obvious reasons `AllowOverride` cannot be set in the `.htaccess` itself.

Furthermore, as Col. Shrapnel mentioned, PHP must be used as Apache module to be able to change PHP's configuration settings via Apache's configuration. Check the Apache error log to see the actual reason.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I tested it. And switching from `AllowOverride All` to `AllowOverride AuthConfig` produces an internal server error on the next request. Of course this does not happen with `AllowOverride None`, because then `.htaccess` is never read by Apache.